# Not sure why drop down box is not populating the data or selection

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

I am having an issue with drop box in codeigniter. I am not sure why the data is not populating on all my drop boxes, this is an example of one of my drop boxes.

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-7 control-label">Scheduled Area</label><br>
                    <?php $Scheduled_Area=$e->Scheduled_Area; 
                    $db=array('Outbound','Inbound','Claims');?>
                    <div class="col-md-5" >
                        <select name="Scheduled_Area" class="form-control">
                            <?php foreach($db as $d ){ 
                                if($department==$d){    ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $d?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $d?></option>
                                <?}else{?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo $d?>"><?php echo $d?></option>
                                <?php }     }?>

                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not very experienced with CodeIgniter but the code you have provided looks very similar to PHP procedural programming methods

I'm not sure why you have the following code in there. Not sure if it is needed to be honest?

```
$Scheduled_Area=$e->Scheduled_Area;
```

I think where your issue lies is your named array. It currently is $db, I would change it from $db as $db is often already defined within MVC software packages for database purposes and it could be causing a conflict. Try renaming it to see if that helps at all.

Also, nowhere within your code is $department defined so, that may be another issue why things aren't working.

I hope you don't mind but I have tidied your code a little for you, its good practice to concatenate php variables and strings. I have also greatly reduced the amount of php tags you were using for readibility purposes :)

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-7 control-label">Scheduled Area</label><br>
    <?php
        $Scheduled_Area = $e->Scheduled_Area; 
        $options = array("Outbound","Inbound","Claims");
    ?>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <select name="Scheduled_Area" class="form-control">
        <?php
            // Define $department here or the 'selected' attribute will not work
            foreach($options as $option){ 
                if($department == $option){
                    echo "<option value='".$option."' selected='selected'>".$option."</option>";
                }
                else{
                    echo "<option value='".$option."'>".$option."</option>";
                }
            }
        ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I figured what happened I left the name out of the array

Comment: Your way is working better the only thing is how do i get the selected to be the current value?

Comment: You need to make sure that the value of $department (presumably a database value) matches one of the options within the array.

Comment: yup  that was the issue I changed it to Scheduled_Area and it worked

Comment: would you have a php script example to do a mass update to all the records on the grid view? If not no worries I am trying to figure out how to do that